# Declaring an array size of an instance array in a method

Tags: java

I'm trying to declare the array size of the instance array in a method. Is there any way to do it? Thank you.

```
package javaapplication2;

public class JavaApplication2 {

static int size;
static int x[] = new int[size];

public static void main(String[] args) {

    setSize(5);
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        x[i] = i;
    }

}

static void setSize(int i) {

    size = i;

}

}
```

Here's the updated codes. I'm getting an array out of bounds error. I'm assuming because the size did not get declared even like this:

```
package javaapplication2;

public class JavaApplication2 {

static int x[];

public static void main(String[] args) {

    setSize(5);
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        x[i] = i;
    }

}

static void setSize(int i) {

    x = new int[i];

}

}
```

I'm getting this error. Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
at javaapplication2.JavaApplication2.main(JavaApplication2.java:13)
Java Result: 1

Comment: perhaps `static void setSize(int i) {

    size = i;

    x[] = new int[size];

}`

Comment: Why have you changed your code? Now your question doesn't make sense. Neither any of the answers.

Comment: In Java array sizes are not "declared".  They are set dynamically at runtime, when the arrays are created.

Comment: That updated code will not throw ArrayIndexOutOfBounds. You've issue somewhere else.

Comment: It's the only code I'm using in the whole program. I updated the code with the kind of exception it's throwing. Did you run the code on your program? Did it throw an exception too?

Comment: @Ski I copy-pasted your code in a fresh class, and it executed successfully without exception. BTW, where is that `Java Result: 1` coming from?

Comment: I copy-pasted my code into a fresh class, and now it's working fine. I don't get it. There was nothing else in the old class, since I deleted everything before pasting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize the array also in the `setSize()` method, and remove the initializer from the place of declaration.

```
static int size;
static int[] x;

static void setSize(int i) {
    size = i;
    x = new int[i];
}
```

Comment: I changed the code above. It still doesn't initialize the size.

Comment: What would be the benefit of the `size` variable, why not just call `x.length`?

Comment: @Ski What is the issue you're facing with the given change?

Comment: Or not have it at all. I took it out the code, but someone changed the code but to what it was like before.

Comment: @Rohit Jain ArrayOutOfBound error. I'm assuming because the array size is still at 0.

Comment: @Ski Of course it has to be reverted. You should never change the original question, else the answer doesn't make sense. See my comment on your question. Rather update the question with new code, and keep the old code.

Comment: @Ski Are you sure you've changed the `setSize()` method to what is in my answer? without any change in `main()` method? If yes, then it should not throw that exception.

Answer (score 3):

Global variables are initialized **before** any constructor or the `main` method, therefore `size` is declared to 0 by default at the time the array is initialized.

Setting `size` to 5 won't help changing the already initialized array.

Comment: Of course it is declared. And even initialized to it's default value `0`.

Answer (score 1):

When your code is executed it runs somewhat like this:

1. The line `static int size` declares the variable `size` and sets its value to `0`, which is the default value for `int`.
2. When you do `static int x[] = new int[size]` the value of `size` is 0. So  `x[]` is initialized as an array of size `0`. This all happens before `main()` gets called.
3. Later, when you change `size` value to `5`, it has no effect on the size of the `x` array, since it was already initialized.

You have two options in this case:

- Set `size` to 5 when you declare it: `static int size = 5`,

or

- Initialize `x[]` only after calling `setSize()`:

  ```
  static int size;
  static int x[];

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      setSize(5);
      x = new int[size];
      ...
  }
  ```